# Can anyone tell me if this is a valid object?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am learning React Native for work, and when I compile and try to render my changes, its telling me that ***"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"***.

Here is my bit of code.

```
const ListScreen = () => {
    
    const friends = [{name:'Friend #1'}]
    
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>List Screen</Text>

            <FlatList style={styles.items}
            data={friends} 
            renderItem={({ friend }) => <Text>{friend.name}</Text>}
            />
         </View>
    )
}



export default ListScreen
```

If you see in my friends array, "name" is basically the key of the object, and the error is telling me its not a valid object. I was referencing the RN docs and a tutorial and they lines up to the way I have my component is written let me know if you post something. My co-workers were stumped on this as well even though it looks pretty simple.

Comment: `({ friend }) => ` should be `(friend) => `

Comment: alternatively you could write `renderItem={({name}) => <Text>{name}</Text>}`. What you can't do is destructure a `friend` property that doesn't exist in the object

Comment: So I tried both of those methods just now, and the error clears but is not rendering the values to screen

Answer (score 1):

It rendered when I provided this:

```
 <FlatList style={styles.items}
            data={friends} 
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
            />
```

The word 'item' must be reserved for this for some reason. I would have thought it would be a arbitrary key name.

Comment: Update to this. I had to research keyExtractor for this. This will explain my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Friends is an array of friend objects so it would look like this:

```
renderItem={({ item: { name } }) => <Text>{name}</Text>}
```

Comment: The values are not being rendered unfortunately. Someone else suggested the samething.

Comment: For some reason after I changed it to "  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}" it works.

Comment: Its the correct answer, you probably have a different issue now. Such as CSS? There's not enough context to know here.

Comment: Hi Justin, someone else suggested the same and it didn't render like I mentioned earlier. There wasn't anything pointing to my css as was not using css at the moment. I do appreciate your input though.

Comment: Ok, I see. They put it on a sub object called `item`. I updated the answer to reflect that, but the main problem in the original was destructuring as `{ friend }` which I would have expected the object to be the friend object itself but in this case they put it onto an `{ item }` field so hopefully its accurate now.